# iPhone - Carousel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, carousel, icarousel

I use open source, `iCarousel` in my application to bring the carousel control. The carousel type which I use is `iCarouselTypeRotary` and the images are arranged linearly in this type. But, I need the images to bring like the carousel in the attached images. What should I do to make my carousel little tilted to the top view as the style in the below images? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement 3D tilt manually:

In `iCarousel.m`: `574`

```
return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius * sin(angle), 0.0f, radius * cos(angle) - radius);
```

change to:

```
float tilt = MAX_TILT_VALUE * cos(angle); // greater angle means greater vertical offset
return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius * sin(angle), tilt, radius * cos(angle) - radius);
```

To make the code clear and reusable, implement tilt offset as option (similar to `iCarouselOptionArc`).

PS: If you want perspective scaling, you will need to add scale transform that depends on `cos(angle)` similarly to `tilt`.

Answer (score 0):

Check by using the style:`iCarouselTypeWheel` use the horizontal wheel set the radius of the wheel as you want. I have done this in vertical wheel type. But i think it should the appearance as above using horizontal wheel type.