# Tweaking iCarousel

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to tweak iCarousel in order to achieve this carousel:

[image]

I'm using iCarousel : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Here is is my current work:

[image]

So what I need to do now is to change carousel perspective and enlarge central item. I'm a little bit lost, found this post related to same issue:

[iPhone - Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246237/iphone-carousel)

So I modified iCarousel class in this way:

```
- (CATransform3D)transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{   
    //set up base transform
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = _perspective;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -_viewpointOffset.width, -_viewpointOffset.height, 0.0f);

    //perform transform
    switch (_type)
    {
        case iCarouselTypeCustom:
        {
            if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:)])
            {
                return [_delegate carousel:self itemTransformForOffset:offset baseTransform:transform];
            }

            //else, fall through to linear transform
        }
        case iCarouselTypeLinear:
        {
            CGFloat spacing = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f];
            if (_vertical)
            {
                return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, offset * _itemWidth * spacing, 0.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset * _itemWidth * spacing, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            }
        }
        case iCarouselTypeRotary:
        {
            CGFloat count = [self circularCarouselItemCount];
            CGFloat spacing = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f];
            CGFloat arc = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionArc withDefault:M_PI * 2.0f];
            CGFloat radius = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:fmaxf(_itemWidth * spacing / 2.0f, _itemWidth * spacing / 2.0f / tanf(arc/2.0f/count))];
            CGFloat angle = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionAngle withDefault:offset / count * arc];

            if (_type == iCarouselTypeInvertedRotary)
            {
                radius = -radius;
                angle = -angle;
            }

            if (_vertical)
            {
                return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, radius * sin(angle), radius * cos(angle) - radius);
            }
            else
            {
                float MAX_TILT_VALUE = 3.0f;
                float tilt = MAX_TILT_VALUE * cos(angle); // greater angle means greater vertical offset
                return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius * sin(angle), tilt, radius * cos(angle) - radius);
            }
        }
```

By the way, I'm using iCarouselTypeRotary. I was tweaking all the values with no luck.I will appreciate your help, I like graphic programming it's new to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked with the radius and number of visible items?

Comment: How can I change it? I checked different iCarousel properties, but I can't find radius or visible items. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can make an effect close to what you are trying to achieve:

```
    case iCarouselTypeInvertedRotary:
    {
        ...
        //-- you might need to multiply radius by a certain factor to make the carousel appear denser:
        CGFloat radius = 0.35 * [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:fmaxf(_itemWidth * spacing / 2.0f, _itemWidth * spacing / 2.0f / tanf(arc/2.0f/count))];

        ...

        else
        {

            //-- for the not inverted case, you need to add
            //-- an y-axis translation factor to add depth-tilting of the carousel plane
            //-- + a factor to increase depth-scaling effect:

            return CATransform3DTranslate(transform,
                            radius * sin(angle),
                            0.5 * radius * cos(angle),
                            2.0 * (radius * cos(angle) - radius));
        }
    }
```

I have used sample values that you might need to tweak to get the correct effect.

btw, the correct way to do this is not modifying `transformForItemView`, rather you need to made your carousel into a `iCarouselTypeCustom` and then return the transform in your delegate `carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:`.

Comment: many thanks Sergio! Btw, can you give some guide lines about depth-scaling effect and depth-titlting? I will appreciate it.

Comment: @sergio can you please tell me where can i put this code?

Comment: @MaulikVekariya: as I suggested, the correct way to do that is using a `iCarouselTypeCustom` carousel and return the transform I defined above from the delegate's `carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:`. If you prefer hacking iCarousel source, just modify the `transformForItemView:` method as above.

Comment: How did you set the alpha on the item based on offset?